# The python bot that executes google analytics javascript

Tags: javascript, python, web, google-analytics, bots

I'm, trying to create some python bot wich can execute google analytics script to cheat visits on my site. 
It's only for education and more can not be used.

So here is my code:

```
import urllib
import mechanize
import socks
import socket
import time
import threading
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# make it like a browser
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent','chrome')]

# use proxies
...
socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "....", ..., True)
socket.socket =  socks.socksocket

# queries  
queryip = "http://whatismyip...com/"
query = "http://www.example...com/"

# visits counter  
global visitscounter
visitscounter = 0

# main function 
def main():
    htmltextip = br.open(queryip).read()
    htmltext = br.open(query).read() 
    #prints
    print (htmltextip)
    print (htmltext)
    #counter +1
    global visitscounter
    print 'Visits: ',visitscounter
    visitscounter = visitscounter +1 
    # do something here ...
    # call main() again in 60 seconds
    threading.Timer(60, main).start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It works but google analytics does not count this visits.
Any ideas?

Here is example of google analytics code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-....-1', 'example.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

The javascript code you can see here http://google-analytics.com/analytics.js

And make it beautiful here http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: *mechanize* doesn't execute JavaScript.

Comment: It might be simpler to fake visits using the measurement protocol (maybe even implementing this serverside, but it work work without js in any case).